# ASP.NET MVC Core 1.0 (aka ASP.NET 5 MVC 6) binary data to image file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC Core 1.0 (aka ASP.NET 5 MVC 6) how to convert binary data (byte[]) to an image file ("image/jpeg") to be save ("wwwroot/images" folder).
Remember: System.Drawing (Image class)  and System.Web.Helpers (WebImage) does not exits anymore.

Alternative solution:

```
  var path = "c:\\Temp\\HC1.jpg";
  byte [] buffer = null;

  // image file to binary data
  if (System.IO.File.Exists (path)) {
    using (var stream = System.IO.File.Open (path, System.IO.FileMode.Open)) {
      var len = stream.Length;
      buffer = new byte [len];
      stream.Read (buffer, 0, (int) len);
      stream.Close ();
    }
  }

  // binary data to image file
  System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes ("c:\\Temp\\HC11.jpg", buffer);
```